# Why do people use "he/she" than "they"?

Tags: pronouns

I often see in particular Americans use the words "he/she" (also sometimes "he or she") as a gender-neutral pronoun.

This is grammatically incorrect (the sentence "he/she" makes no grammatical sense), it's clumsy, it's long (two syllables), and, to be a bit pedantic, it doesn't even solve the problem of gender bias, because why is it "he/she" and not "she/he"?

On the other hand, we have the perfectly viable alternative of using "they". It's short, it's grammatically correct, it's completely neutral, it just works.

So why do so many speakers use the clumsy "he/she" rather than the elegant "they"?

Comment: Are you also saying that *use 1 than 2* is elegant and that saying *use 1 rather than 2* is clumsy?

Comment: It's overworked. But if most people (or even a significant number) use 'he/she' or 'he or she' rather than 'they', this establishes 'correct grammar'. Arguing otherwise is like saying that all the people who use 'It's us' (ie 99+% of Anglophones) are being ungrammatical. Extragrammatical (ie outside normal grammar) idioms exist.

Comment: The short answer is that it actually *is* grammatical (or arguably so). But whether it should be used is one of style. Most style guides will say it should not be used in formal writing. And those people who don't like *they* object to it on the grounds that they don't believe it should be used as a singular gender-neutral pronoun. Again, this is a matter of style. (Although they can argue it's ungrammatical, as many people can argue that it isn't.) In theory, using *it* could also be used—but that has very little traction.

Comment: 'They' can get confusing: "_The player_ **has** the ball and _they_ now **have** to pass it to the opposition." So, it doesn't seem to always work.

Answer (score 0):

I would read he/she aloud with three syllables, saying the "or".

Sometimes context or style, or avoidance of repetition might demand, or be thought to make preferable, the use of phrases that make the reader think of one theoretical individual in the scenario described, making it more personal than it would be if we used a generic abstract "they".

Personally, I would sooner SAY he/she than write it, for what that's worth.